# Can you add a .php file to your .html file?

Tags: php, html

I have a website made and i have saved the file as .html, I now want to add a .php file. Is this possible as i have tried so hard to do this. Id appreciate any help given :)

Comment: does your hosting support it?

Comment: any help on how to make it clearer please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do several things.

- Rename your .html files to .php.
- Tell your web server to pass .html files to the PHP interpreter. In Apache you'd do this by putting `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` in your .htaccess file or your Apache configuration.

Comment: [several](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/several) (aka more than **two**) :-P

Comment: @Neal - Technically, there's no conflict. He didn't actually say he was listing all of the several.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PHP, you can rename your file to `*.php` and insert PHP codes!

Answer (score 0):

You want to put PHP code inside a .html file? You'd have to configure the webserver to treat the .html file as a PHP script. Technically, there's no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which have at least one `<?php ?>` code block within them. As such, **ANY** file can contain PHP code. The problem is getting that file into the PHP environment.

Unless your webserver is told to hand the .html file over to the PHP interpreter, you cannot execute the PHP code contained within it - the raw code will get sent out as part of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your .html file to .php, if your webhost supports it.

If you run your own server you can even configure PHP to also run .html files, but it's not recommended because of the performance penalty on all html files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include php file into html file. i m sure that this link will help you.
http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm